# After undoing changes, Neovim still requires saving file or ! before exit

Tags: vimrc, neovim

If I open a file, add a line (`o`), and then delete that line (`dd`) making the file exactly the same as when it was opened, upon exiting (`:q`), Neovim states:

```
E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)
```

This behavior did not exist previously. I recently updated some packages though. How can I get back being able to exit without saving after making a change and then undoing that change?

#### Further Research

If I undo the change (`u`) instead of deleting the line that was added (`dd`), Neovim will quit without requiring a save or ! to override.

Comment: You first say you are deleting the line then you say you are undoing it. Can we assume you really mean undo for both? (Deleting a line you just added isn't the same as undoing it...it won't be back at the original state.)

Comment: Note: My comment was sent right before I saw your edit. Sounds like you did mean delete rather than undo. Like I noted, the delete is a new action that adds a node to the undo history. It's not a reversal of a previous action. Thus you must save or force quit.

Comment: I'd like the community's input on this one but I think this question should be closed as it is just the default behavior.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the behavior described is intentional and as-designed.

Answer (score 2):

This is default behaviour of Vim. Vim notices, the buffer has been modified and just warns you of quitting and (possibly) losing your changes. This is done by setting the `modified` option for the buffer you are currently editing.

However, despite its name, it does not mean that the current buffer differs from the state on disk, but rather whether a change has been done to the buffer being edited, even if it is a no-op, so e.g. <kbd>r</kbd> with the same letter the cursor is on, will behave the same and set the `modified` option, preventing you from an accidental `:q`.

However when undoing, Vim will reset the `modified` flag, because this information is also stored in the undo buffer, so that's why it works differently.

It has been requested to change that behaviour (e.g. in this [bug](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2700)), but that would be a backward incompatible change and I tend to agree. In fact, I do actually like this feature.